# How regular expression ANDY X - XXXXX - XXXXX

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for this formate.

X are integers and N is 1 or more[1 to infinity]. ANDY can be lower or upper case

```
ANDY N: XXXXX - XXXXX

/^[\iANDY]\s[\d]{1,}\s[0-9]{4}\s-\s[0-9]{4}$/
```

May I know how to make N more than 0 for this regular expression? and is there anyway to improve it?

Comment: sorry I type the solution in a rush. I work in the mountain cave so I can't actually "paste" the code from the development pc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure it's more than `0` use this:

```
[1-9]\d*
```

As in 1 digit that is between 1 and 9, followed by any number of digits between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, `N != 0`? Just make it not to start with `0` but `[1-9]`, and then any number of digits. Also, you could just use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`. And I guess "ANDY" should not be a character class. And I'm not sure which engine you use, but the usual escape- and special character is the *back*slash.

```
/^ANDY\s[1-9]\d*\s\d{4}\s-\s\d{4}$/i
```